# Which one of methods should I choose for deployment of smart contract geth or a wallet if I have to build API for smart contracts in nodejs?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm having trouble to understand which method would be better for deployment geth or a wallet if I'm building API in `nodejs` using `web3`.

Where exactly is the contract stored??

Is the contract independent of wallet when deployed from wallet??

In both cases will I need the private key of smart contract in `web3` or the account which launched the smart contract to invoke its functionality??

If I close the `geth` node the smart contract should still run smoothly right??

Answer (score 0):

Smart contracts don't have private keys, only your accounts do. your wallet underlying is probably using geth, it doesnt matter what node you use to deploy as long as it is synced to the mainchain. you use the ABI and contract address, which you pass in your web3 instance to invoke your contract functions

Comment: currently my contract is deployed through the geth node so my node app interacts on the port 8545, if I'm to deploy it in a wallet I'll get the address of the smart contract, What will be the network address in case of main network and the ropsten network?? Also will the invoking of functionality of contract through web3  require me to unlock the account where it was deplloyed from??

Comment: @ShubhabrataMukherjee you are getting things mixed up, you are not deploying to your wallet, your deploying to the main network, your wallet is only a means for that, that port no is for your node/wallet that you are using not the network itself